# How do I copy elements from one sheet to another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

This is a slightly complicated question because it has two dimensions.

I have a row of formulas in one sheet in a workbook in Excel. I want to copy the numbers in that row as a *column* to another sheet in the workbook so that if I make a change in the row in the original sheet, it will propagate the change to the right place in the column.

The two dimensions are: transpose of a row to a column and copying across sheets.

How is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `Transpose` to copy data from a row and paste it into a column (copy the area, Paste Special, `Tranpose`). This will not preserve a link between what is found in the row and what is placed in the column. If you want this link to exist to reflect changes to the row in the column, you should link to the cell directly using, for example, `=A1`.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since this isn't a service site, there is an expectation that you have attempted something. New members commonly forget to add details of what they have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas. Please add those details so we can help you. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, here is the formula for this :

To copy and transpose between Excel workbooks:

```
=OFFSET([filename.xlsx]SheetName!$A$1,MOD(ROWS([filename.xlsx]SheetName!$2:2)-1,4),ROUNDUP(ROWS([filename.xlsx]SheetName$2:2)/4,0)-1)
```

just change the **filename** and **SheetName** to the correct names.

To copy and transpose between sheets within an Excel workbook:

```
=OFFSET(SheetName!$A$1,MOD(ROWS(SheetName!$2:2)-1,4),ROUNDUP(ROWS(SheetName$2:2)/4,0)-1)
```

just change the **SheetName** to the correct names.

Just use the formula in any cell, and it will automatically will copy and transpose the cells.

Thanks to **[Gary's Student](https://superuser.com/questions/1058246/stack-ranges-into-1-column)** for this formula.