# Stack Ranges into 1 Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, join

If I had two columns by 4 rows:

`A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
A4 B4`

I would like the result

`A1
A2
A3
A4
B1
B2
B3
B4`

I've used choose function to combine different ranges before ... but it doesn't seem to like stacking things into one array. *I.e `=CHOOSE({1;2},A1:A4,B1:B4)`*

In google sheets you can simply *`={A1:A4;B1:B4}`* To achieve the same result. How do I do this in excel without VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a cell, enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4),ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)-1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

***Note:***

Using similar formulas, you can map any 2-D table into a single column or a single row in either row order or column order.

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid copy/paste, first select the block of eight cells from **C5** through **C12**, then click in the formula bar and type the formula, and enter it using <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Is it possible to do this as an array that doesn't require copying and pasting?

Comment: @Xzila There is  only coping down a single formula.

Comment: Bummer about no array version. Thank you for your answer. The modulus, round-up technique is pretty interesting.

Comment: @Xzila  To avoid the copy/paste, see my **EDIT#1**